# TypeScript - type guarding a class generic?

Tags: typescript

How to make work in TS a generic class that can return different types based on its generic parameter (set in the constructor)?

```
type Type = 'foo' | 'bar';

interface Res {
    'foo': {foo: number};
    'bar': {bar: string};
}

class MyClass<T extends Type> {
    constructor(readonly type: T) {}

    public run(): Res[T] {
        if (is(this, 'foo')) {
            return { foo: 123 };
        }
        return { bar: 'xyz' };
    }
}

function is<T extends Type>(instance: MyClass<Type>, type: T): instance is MyClass<T> {
    return instance.type === type;
}
```

As it can be checked in the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oHIBmB7dyoB8UCMBDAJ2QG4BYAKGoEsA7YCY1QgY2gCUIBnKAb2pRhKDFgBcAsZPoBXALb5mAX0pURBEskn8ixST2DEGAc1XVl1amwA2hHnwCyIAMJ2HAHhhQIADyb0ACZ8cJAAfAJCImzo9IbEsmzA6MQAFMQQhIGxNiBQoJCSMACUApY06iJgsvg2tGxQCfSpxZLcPADaMAC6kZUawrSoUKm0PKnAABZjADSimMjFpYL9AxoZwLLE9AJQ0lAAjABMAMxQ5qsa5WvCG1s7-FB6ksi+IABe2BdXFlZUqLJ6ElaLEoGMvD5-BAgiF4GFRnFgIQgRBJM43PYeF44XMCqjYK0wYjkRwwU5XO4sTAIit1hBNtsiYYSRAAHR4qAILn5eBqZRAA), this example gives the following error:

> Type '{ foo: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Res[T]'.
> Type '{ foo: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ foo: number; } & { bar: string; }'.
> Property 'bar' is missing in type '{ foo: number; }' but required in type '{ bar: string; }'.

but common sense (and the type guard) is stating that the generic `T` is clearly the correct type... so why is it not applied to the return line?

Comment: Control flow analysis and generics don't play together.  You are narrowing `this` but not `T`.  [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) is the open feature request to support code like what you're writing; until and unless that's implemented then you either need to use type assertions or to refactor away from control flow analysis and use generic indexing instead, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WGGGvW).  If that fully addresses the question I'll post an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That is an interesting approach for sure, and it solves the problem, thanks! But doesn't seem like a very natural way to code... it's like you need another small class inside the class (that mapping) to return the typed result... I was expecting that narrowing the generic type of `this` will also narrow its result but I can see it's not the case

Comment: Modified @jcalz solution [in this other playground](https://tsplay.dev/m0OeoN) to provide a somehow more OOP-like solution but still typed... I guess this is it... ?

Comment: haha yeah I realized it... thought it was automatic ^^;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) don't really work very well together in TypeScript.  When you check `is(this, 'foo')`, the [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) can narrow the apparent type of `this` to `this & MyClass<"foo">`, but it has no effect whatsoever on the generic type parameter `T`.  You might expect or hope that `T` would be re-[constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) from `Type` to just `"foo"`, but it's not.  And that means `{foo: 123}` cannot be known to be assignable to `Res[T]`, and you get an error.

Note that while it might seem "obvious" that `this.type === "foo"` should imply `T` is `"foo"`, it is actually incorrect to do so in general.  That's because `T` *might* be specified by the full [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `"foo" | "bar"`, and establishing that `this.type === "foo"` would not let you eliminate that possibility. At best you can say that you know that `T` must have some overlap with `"foo"`, so that `T & "foo"` is not `never`, but this is very tricky sort of constraint to enforce or express.

There are several open feature requests asking for some way of re-constraining generic type parameters via control flow analysis. The most relevant ones for this code example here are [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) which would let you force `T` to only be *one of* `"foo"` and `"bar"` and never the union; and [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) which would let the compiler see that even if `T` were the full union, it would be safe to return `{foo: 123}`.  Either one would probably make your code work as-is, but for now they are not part of the language and you need to work around it.

---

The easiest workaround is just to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler not to worry about verifying the types.  For example:

```
public run(): Res[T] {
    if (is(this, 'foo')) {
        return { foo: 123 } as Res[T]; // okay
    }
    return { bar: 'xyz' } as Res[T]; // okay
}
```

This is the most expedient way for you to move forward with a minimum of changes to your code.  But just beware that you're taking the responsibility for type checking away from the compiler here.  You could change the check above to `(!is(this, 'foo'))` and the compiler would still be happy with it. So you have to be careful when making type assertions that you are telling the truth.

---

If it's more important to get some type safety guarantees from the compiler here, then the workaround will involve refactoring away from type guarding and control flow analysis, and toward generic *indexing*.  Your intended return type is the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `Res[T]`, so if you want the compiler to understand that, you can index into an object of type `Res` with a key of type `T` and return that:

```
public run(): Res[T] {
    return {
        foo: { foo: 123 },
        bar: { bar: 'xyz' }
    }[this.type]; // okay
}
```

That might look weird but it is similar to the logic of checking `this.type` and then directing control flow based on the result.  The only major difference here is that the runtime will actually compute both possible return values `{foo: 123}` and `{bar: 'xyz'}` every time `run()` is called, even though it throws away one of them.  For small object literals without side effects like this, it probably doesn't matter. But if you really want to have the same behavior as before, you can use [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to make sure that only the code block corresponding to the actual `this.type` value is executed:

```
public run(): Res[T] {
    return {
        get foo() { return { foo: 123 } },
        get bar() { return { bar: 'xyz' } }
    }[this.type]; // okay
}
```

Now id `this.type` is `"foo"`, `return {foo: 123}` will run but `return {bar: 'xyz'}` will not.

You could modify this implementation to do other things, but the basic approach is that you are implementing an indexed access type via an actual indexing operation, and not via `if`/`else` statements.

---

So there you go. The language is not ready for generics and type guards together, and you can work around it either by relaxing the type checking, or by using generics without type guards.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBKUICcAuSDeAsAFBKlLYCeMyAKlcgLxIDkAZgPbvNIA+LARiEzMA3MWJkkAS2DYsrBMgBK0fBMlk2nZgC58SDuz3AArmH5YkAXzEkNpZoOF68SJ3qjZMMgObXbklbidqTwADYg6EgAshQAwhHoADw0SBAAHnLAACZQSHTUAHxqIRrw7MCemCbw2OyYABSYECDZFWEU5PR6NACU+kFE6vYwJvxhUvBI1cANvXoqUADaNAC6Jfb2UqxIDVJQDdgAFvsANCyGzL39hKWbGs3YJpjA+oZ6AIwATADM1kiRJCLFarERIAD04KQ7AA1iAKMN7tZEfdHs9Xq53Cx0hQAF7cKwAvLAtZgyHQuEIu5kQaBYKSVgmYC1KQVaRQFJpTIQHJ5AoQQp7SrYEDMiB6WIJSIc-mFc6Uag9ebSYWixDsmLxRIy4q3VEQJ4vFWeNUQAB0CsYDCYloCNOIg2IoEgsEUQIgClq9Q2ZEt+XoSCYWi4vAEQlE9LIMjkmE9ylUes2wd0b04xjMFkw-hRmicKcxQg8Xl82dKjtK4WlmqlyQA0lysrl-UUffZysLql7Gs1Wu1Opa9LWbsihtTSKNxpNpky5gtoEta+tE0jpgb0a2V2QfAaDJw5vo0UbXO8kN8-oSrKccyvt7gnPvXIeMW5C9i8QSR5vrEtjvsLfRQWvT97VHB0gA)

Comment: This is the key: `That's because T might be specified by the full union type "foo" | "bar"`

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I don't think it is possible to restrict the return type of a function from within the function. I believe the best you can do is to remove the error with a typecast:

```js
public run(): Res[T] {
    if (is(this, 'foo')) {
        return { foo: 123 } as Res[T];
    }
    return { bar: 'xyz' } as Res[T];
}
```

Original answer:

I suspect that Typescript doesn't know how to narrow your call to `is(this, 'foo')` because your function definition for `is` doesn't use `T`:

```js
function is<T extends Type>(instance: MyClass<Type>, type: Type): instance is MyClass<T>
```

should probably be:

```js
function is<T extends Type>(instance: MyClass<Type>, type: T): instance is MyClass<T>
```

So that the compiler can narrow based on the type of the 2nd argument. Alternatively you could specify the generic argument when calling it like this: `is<'foo'>(this, 'foo')`

Comment: oops! sorry, my code was using your answer... I just wrote it wrong in the playground when trying to provide a minimal example.
And no, it doesn't solve it... let me update the original question and the link to the playground...

Comment: Yes, using a typecast is what I have now in my repo but I realized that if I add new types to the `Type` list, then there will be no checks at all and wanted to avoid that if possible so... asking the experts ;)